# Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strlen()

Tags: php, symfony, vps, iconv

My project works fine on localhost but not working online and this is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strlen() in /home/stram/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 338
```

I googled it and I found that I need to install the PHP extension `iconv`. The problem that I'm using a VPS and when I went to the list of available PHP extensions I didn't found this extension !
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Try the symfony polyfills (https://github.com/symfony/polyfill)

Comment: @qooplmao thnx for your response and I should just install it with composer ? I mean I don't have to do anything except installation ?

Comment: @qooplmao thank you it was helpfull :)

Comment: @Slimen I have the same problem, how to do for fix the error?

Comment: @nabil you need to download symfony/polyfill-iconv (https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/polyfill-iconv) via composer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Symfony provides an iconv-polyfill for cases like that. Just add it as requirement to your project, and you should be fine:

```
composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv
```

Comment: Thnx it worked. Also thnx to @qooplmao for his answer :)

Comment: @Michael I have the same problem, how to do for fix the error?

Comment: @nabil didn't my solution work for you too? If so, please open up a new question and provide as many information as you can. You maybe need a different solution for a different problem.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution with cpanel WHM : http://cyberpersons.com/2016/10/21/install-missing-php-extensions-cpanelwhm/

Answer (score 8):

It may also happen that you are using an outdated version of PHP, **or** one that was compiled without iconv.

To check that, run `php --ri iconv` with any SSH software, like Putty, etc.

If it shows ***Extension 'iconv' not present.***, your problem is in PHP. Then you have a few options:

- Run php -v to check your PHP version, and update it if necessary
- Or compile PHP again with iconv
- Or enable iconv on WHM/cPanel, if you use them
- Or ask your hosting company for support

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution to your problem (command line is for CentOS) :

[image: EasyApache]

Answer (score 4):

Solved: If you are using **Cpanel/WHM STACK** then follow:
Go to WHM >> EasyApache4 >> Current Installed Packages >> customize

Now Select **php extensions** and search for **iconv** and **debug** install both of them and try to install again.. enjoy :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use WHM with the CentOS 7 operating system you will encounter errors like this when typing "composer" on the console:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv() in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php:661
Stack trace:

0 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php(48): Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\Mbstring::mb_strwidth('help', 'ASCII')

......

The solution is to install the iconv package using WHM:

Enter to your WHM then type "EasyApache 4" then click "EasyApache 4" and click "Customize". you can see in the picture

[EasyApache 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjzhP.png)

Select PHP Extensions, type "iconv" in the search and check the version of php that you will use to install the iconv package. see in the picture

[PHP Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY7o2.png)

Choose Review

[Review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quDFs.png)

Click Provision

[Provision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO7rv.png)

To ensure that the iconv package is installed you can use this command "php --ri iconv" if the results are like this in the picture. then the iconv package has succeeded. try typing the composer again so you don't get any more errors

[php --ri iconv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VOi6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I installed Mbstring extension but did not restart Apache.

All that needed is to do

```
$ sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2/apache2.wrapper restart
```

Yeah, I have a long path here, but it is just for me. It is because I use MacPorts

To find your Apache location use

```
$ ps ax | grep apache
```

P.S.

I don't have `iconv` extension installed too. At list it is not listed when I call php info like so:

```
die(phpinfo());
```

BTW

it is really easy to install extension with MacPorts, For my `PHP 5.6` I have done just:

```
$ sudo port install php56-mbstring
```