# Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() error laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-5.4

I am uploading a laravel 5.4 project to cpanel server.
And i am serve with

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos()
```

on server.

I have done

```
composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv
```

However, it does not change the error message.
What thing i might miss out?

Comment: use composer dump in your console

Comment: This might help: http://cyberpersons.com/2016/10/21/install-missing-php-extensions-cpanelwhm/

Comment: Cpanel will inevitably cause problems. I would recommend picking up a $5 vps from [linode](http://linode.com) or [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv\_strlen()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800616/call-to-undefined-function-symfony-polyfill-mbstring-iconv-strlen)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that you have php-iconv and php-mbstring installed on the server. Then check again. By default, mbstring is not installed on cPanel/WHM servers