# Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found

Tags: php

I am trying to use digital ocean spaces in my php7 laravel project. The code is pretty simple to just load a file and copy it to the directory. Everything works on my local machine but fails on my digital ocean server with this error

> Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found

Even on digital ocean server, if I use tinker to run the same storage commands, it works fine. What can be the issue?

My `get_loaded_extensions()` returns
get_loaded_extensions()

```
[
     "Core",
     "date",
     "libxml",
     "openssl",
     "pcre",
     "zlib",
     "filter",
     "hash",
     "pcntl",
     "Reflection",
     "SPL",
     "session",
     "standard",
     "mysqlnd",
     "PDO",
     "xml",
     "apcu",
     "calendar",
     "ctype",
     "curl",
     "dom",
     "mbstring",
     "fileinfo",
     "ftp",
     "gd",
     "gettext",
     "iconv",
     "json",
     "exif",
     "mysqli",
     "pdo_mysql",
     "Phar",
     "posix",
     "readline",
     "shmop",
     "SimpleXML",
     "sockets",
     "sysvmsg",
     "sysvsem",
     "sysvshm",
     "tokenizer",
     "wddx",
     "xmlreader",
     "xmlrpc",
     "xmlwriter",
     "xsl",
     "zip",
     "Zend OPcache",
   ]
```

so it looks like xml and simplexml are installed. As suggested by the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223926/class-simplexmlelement-not-found-on-puphpet-php-5-6), `php-xml` and `php-simplexml` should be installed. Do I need to install something separately?

Also, my file upload code looks like this

```
public function uploadNew($file, $title, User $user)
    {
        if (!File::directoryExists($user->username)) {
            Storage::makeDirectory($user->username);
        }
        $completeFileName = $user->username.'/'.$title.time();
        Storage::put($completeFileName, file_get_contents($file), 'public');
        $this->url = File::baseUrl().$completeFileName;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->user_id = $user->id;
        $this->save();
        return $this;
    }

    public static function baseUrl()
    {
        return 'https://'.env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET').'.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/';
    }

    public static function directoryExists($directory)
    {
        $existingDirs = Storage::directories();
        return in_array($directory, $existingDirs);
    }
```

Adding the stack trace of exception:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found
in PayloadParserTrait.php (line 39)
at RestXmlParser->parseXml(object(Stream))
in RestXmlParser.php (line 33)
at RestXmlParser->payload(object(Response), object(StructureShape), array())
in AbstractRestParser.php (line 62)
at AbstractRestParser->__invoke(object(Command), object(Response))
in RetryableMalformedResponseParser.php (line 37)
at RetryableMalformedResponseParser->__invoke(object(Command), object(Response))
in AmbiguousSuccessParser.php (line 58)
at AmbiguousSuccessParser->__invoke(object(Command), object(Response))
in GetBucketLocationParser.php (line 30)
at GetBucketLocationParser->__invoke(object(Command), object(Response))
in WrappedHttpHandler.php (line 126)
at WrappedHttpHandler->parseResponse(object(Command), object(Request), object(Response), array())
in WrappedHttpHandler.php (line 93)
at WrappedHttpHandler->Aws\{closure}(object(Response))
in Promise.php (line 203)
```

Comment: Check for namespace, you might need to call with `\SimpleXMLElement`

Comment: Its somewhere in AWS library...nowhere in my code.

Comment: May be this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35834836/3305978

Comment: I attached the same link in my question. As I have shown in the extensions list, xml and simplexml is already present but when I run extensions_loaded('php-xml'), it returns false. Do I have to install php7.0-xml or simplexml separately?

Answer (score 26):

check the version of installed php using:-

```
$ php -v
```

If it's version 7, then install **php7.0-xml**

if it's version 7.2.*, then use **php7.2-xml** package on your machine along with php.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml` for ubuntu and php 7.0

Comment: I am using php 8 on Ubuntu 20.04 and php-xml is installed on my server but that doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 11):

Just install php-xml package.For reference, just install all the additional php libraries:

apt-get install php-pear php7.2-curl php7.2-dev php7.2-gd php7.2-mbstring php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml

Comment: I am using php 8 on Ubuntu 20.04 and installed all the mentioned packages but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Did you changed the packages as per PHP 8? This is for 7.2

Answer (score 8):

Finally, I just had to follow the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223926/class-simplexmlelement-not-found-on-puphpet-php-5-6) I have mentioned in question.  installed php7.0-xml and simplexml had to be installed and apache server restarted to get it to work. So, even if your loaded extensions show xml and simplexml as installed, you might still need to install the php7.0-xml and simplexml.

Answer (score 8):

You have to put \ slash in front of SimpleXMLElement (in laravel) in order to call xml element class

```
$url = "https://abc.xyz.com";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$xmlDoc = new \SimpleXMLElement($response);
```

Answer (score 6):

To fix this, install the latest version of php-xml, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml -y
```

Don't forget to restart apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved running this command

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
use SimpleXMLElement;
```

before calling the class.

Comment: In my file? I am not using this class directly and in the library where they are using it they are actually using it correctly. But anyways, I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: This is helpful if you use this class in another class (OOP approach)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this in a Docker container and found that I hadn't actually installed and enabled SimpleXML like I thought.  `phpinfo()` mentioned SimpleXML but, if there's not a section titled "SimpleXML" that says:

```
SimpleXML support   enabled
```

then SimpleXML isn't there.  Even if `php-xml` is added and enabled, SimpleXML isn't.

To fix it, I had to add `php-simplexml` (or, in my case, `php81-simplexml` for PHP 8.1) to my Dockerfile and then everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

**I faced the same issues after upgrading PHP to version 8.2 using [Alpine image version 3.18](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/alpine/3.18/images/sha256-c0669ef34cdc14332c0f1ab0c2c01acb91d96014b172f1a76f3a39e63d1f0bda?context=explore) and upgrading [`aws/aws-sdk-php` dependency](https://packagist.org/packages/aws/aws-sdk-php) to latest version (at the time of writing this post it was version `3.281.14`).**

Normally it is necessary to install `xml` and `simplexml` packages that are valid for your installed version of PHP, e.g. for PHP 8.1 it was `php81-xml` and `php81-simplexml`. Everything worked fine with these dependencies on PHP 8.1.

**After upgrading to PHP 8.2 and Alpine image version 3.18, having `php82-xml` and `php82-simplexml` installed didn't satisfy the `aws/aws-sdk-php` dependency I had in my `composer.json` file**, it was throwing following error:

```
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - aws/aws-sdk-php is locked to version 3.281.14 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - aws/aws-sdk-php 3.281.14 requires ext-simplexml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's simplexml extension.
```

Falling back to use `php81-xml` and `php81-simplexml` dependencies (despite running PHP 8.2 version) has helped to resolve the above issue, but then I faced the runtime issue you described: `Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found`

**The solution that has helped me to resolve the issue for PHP 8.2 on Alpine 3.18 was to install both dependencies for PHP 8.1 (`php81-xml` and `php81-simplexml`) and for PHP 8.2 (`php82-xml` and `php82-simplexml`). There was no issue installing all those 4 dependencies despite them being for different versions of PHP, they can all be installed next to each other.**

**On top of that, I had to install `php82-iconv` dependency to fix further issues with missing `iconv` dependency for PHP 8.2. The issue I faced was described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800616/call-to-undefined-function-symfony-polyfill-mbstring-iconv-strlen) and I also added the `symfony/polyfill-iconv` dependency to my `composer.json` file by running `composer require symfony/polyfill-iconv` as described in the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40801413).**

Answer (score -1):

I just had to restart apache2 after installing

systemctl apache2 restart